# Wput - Upload Folder

Tags: ftp

I've been searching and trying for days to get wput.exe to upload an entire folder, along with its subfolders.  I've been told that Wput can do this.  I've tried the following:

wput C:\upload\  ftp://user:password@172.29.200.158/Transfer/

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the result when you tried?

Comment: Failed to change to target directory. Skipping this file/dir.
-- Skipping file: `C:/upload/C++ Book/Additional Chapters\cpphtp7_24_AU.pdf'
-- Skipping file: `C:/upload/C++ Book/Additional Chapters\cpphtp7_26_ATM2_AU.pdf'
-- Skipping file: `C:/upload/C++ Book/Exercise Answers\ch13solutions.zip'
Receive-Error: read() failed. Read '221 Goo' so far. (errno: No error (0))
Receive-Error: Connection broke down.
FINISHED --13:36:58--
Transmission of 22 files failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use the --basename argument to remove the drive letter.  That way, when wput tries to create a file structure on the ftp server it doesn't include the drive letter in the folder path.

Example:

C:>wput --basename=C:\ C:\upload\ ftp://user:password@172.29.200.158/Transfer/Uploads/

Seems to do the trick.

Comment: Have you seen this error before?  Error: File `--basename=/tmp/motion/' does not exist. Don't know what to do about this URL.

Comment: I answered my own question: make sure you put the PATH part of the --basename option in single quotes!
--basename='/tmp/motion/'
instead of
--basename=/tmp/motion/